# SASS : unedfined variable when @use in an entry file which imports a master sheet

Tags: html, css, web, sass, web-testing

I have 2 websites that have very similar styling, only difference is color schemes and some other minor things.

To make things organized,  using Sass  I have 1 master style sheet ,  2 style sheets that hold variables such as the different colors for each site, and also 2 "entry point" files which are the base files which get compiled,  2 entry point files because 1 for each site.

the 2 entry points include the 1 master style sheet + the site's variable sheet so 5 files in total

I have been using @import  and it has been working well.
However import is being deprecated.
I tried to use @ use  and @forward but with no luck
When I use  USE and FORWARD it gives me "This variable is not defined" error

```
@import 'variablesheet'
@import 'masterstyles'
```

This works
But use and forward dont

```
@use 'variablesheet' as *
@use 'masterstyles' as *
```

How do I do this without import as that is being deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using each stylesheet with it's own namespace. Then you should be able to use the variables from each scss file. If this doesn't work, then you need to provide more details in your question.

```
@use 'variablesheet' as v;
@use 'masterstyles' as m;

.class {
  padding: m.$padding; /*m. is to reference masterstyles*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the time, however I want to clarify that the master styles sheet does NOT have declarations of variables,  it only has nested CSS and things like for loops and interpolation and usage of variables. The point is that I can have a "Base stylesheet" where the variable sheet controls the minor variations on each site. I dont want to make 2 copies of the base style sheet which import from different variable files. Since that would mean when I change one file I would have to change the other